# $(...).serializeJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea why I am getting this error despite include a Jquery library.
My code:

```
 function create() {
        var employeeForm = $("#createUser").serializeJSON();

      var employee = JSON.stringify(employeeForm);

      $.ajax({
        url: uric,
        type: 'POST',
        data: employee,
        success: function(results) {

        }
    });
```

The library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What could I be missing???

Comment: **1.** You've included jQuery twice. **2.** Use [**serialize**](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [**serializeArray**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). **3.** To use `serializeJSON` you need to include https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON library after jQuery

Comment: You're importing jQuery twice - why? And where did you get the idea that `.serializeJSON()` was part of jQuery?

Comment: Ok.  So I need to include  github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON, right?  I am so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new JS script in your project and paste the script from there : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/master/jquery.serializejson.js. Then add then script src to your page.